# PHP скачать файл utf-8 с расширенными символами

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Есть php скрипт, который генерит файл с данными из базы и отдает его на скачивание.

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.kml"');
<? echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
...
```

Ну и так далее. Сам файл utf-8, на сервере utf-8, в `.htaccess` написано `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`. В общем все utf-8 и даже файл, который скачивается, тоже utf-8. Но есть нюанс — если в файле есть символы типа  и , то файл сразу  превращается в ANSI, ну и соответственно крокозябры в кириллице.

Что делать?

Comment: попробуйте передавать его кодированном в unicode codepoints. Типа \u1235\u9887 и т.д. json_encode конвертировать умеет например.

Comment: @rjhdby ммм, не очень понял задумку. а json_encode чего? всей строки, которая содержит этот символ? ну ок, файл стал utf-8, только все равно читать то текст невозможно.

Comment: это я как пример функции, которая так делать умеет может привел. Наверняка через iconv или htmlchars можно конвертировать. Идея в передаче unicode codepoints вместо собственно текста и конвертации его обратно на клиенте. Кстати в сторону бинарного кодирования через base64 можно еще посмотреть, или вообще в zip'е